# How do I determine if the equation is a conservation law?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

We have the PDE
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+a(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+b(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$. What would be conditions on $a$ and $b$ for the equation to constitute a conservation law? I think that $a=b$ would be sufficient, since then the flux of $u$ into a small control volume in a Cartesian coordinate system would affect the growth rate $\partial u / \partial t$ in the same way regardless of the direction which the flux of $u$ comes from. What do you think?

Comment: Assuming you mean $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ in the third term, look up the continuity equation in whatever notes you're working from. You should find that conservation laws correspond to a continuity equation of something like the form $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\nabla\cdot({\bf F} u)$, where ${\bf F}$ is a vector field. Then it is straightforward to derive conditions on the partial derivatives of ${\bf F}$ such that this has the same form as your equation.

Comment: @BaronMingus Yes, it follows that if $\textbf{F}=(F_1 , F_2)$, then $\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}a(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}b(x,y)$. But I don't see how this gives any conditions on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That's not correct. You need to use the product rule for the divergence of the product of a vector field and scalar field.

Comment: @BaronMingus Ok, so we have $\nabla \cdot (\textbf{F} u)=u\nabla \cdot \textbf{F}+(\nabla u)\cdot\textbf{F}=u\left(\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} \right)+F_1 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+F_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, and so we identify $F_1=a$ and $F_2=b$, and the sole condition on $a$ and $b$ is that $\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}$. Correct?

Comment: what if I write : with $\phi :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ a non-linear mapping so $x = \phi_x(x_2,y_2),y= \phi_y(x_2,y_2)$ now $u$ is $u(\phi_x(x_2,y_2),\phi_y(x_2,y_2))$ and $(\partial_t+\partial_{x_2}+\partial_{y_2})u = \partial_t u +(\partial_{x_2}\phi_x +\partial_{y_2}\phi_x)\partial_x u + (\partial_{x_2}\phi_y +\partial_{y_2}\phi_y) \partial_y u$ 

so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$ is $div(u(\phi_x,\phi_y,t) = 0$ if $a = (\partial_{x_2} +\partial_{y_2})\phi_x$ and $b = (\partial_{x_2} +\partial_{y_2})\phi_y$ ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conservation law has the following structure:
$$u_t=-\mathrm{div} (\mathbf{F}(x,y,u))$$
where $\mathbf{F}=(F^1,F^2)^T$ is a vector field that, in principle, can be nonlinear.

The last PDE can be rewritten in the following form:
$$u_t=-{F^1}_x-{F^2}_y-\mathbf{F}_u\cdot \nabla u$$

In your case we have ${F^1}_x={F^2}_y=0$ and this implies $F^1=f(y,u)$ and $F^2=g(x,u)$.

Moreover $\mathbf{F}_u=(a(x,y),b(x,y))^T$ and this means that $\mathbf{F}$ must be linear with respect to $u$. Hence we have $\mathbf{F}_u=(f(y)u+c_1,g(x)u+c_2)^T$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two constants.

**EDIT** (to answer @user1952009)

What you are trying to do is something different. The question which can you pose to my answer is:

Are your calculations independent with respect a change of coordinate? 
Will the function keep the same structure changing the set of coordinates?

The answer is clearly o because at some point I started to use the definition of divergence in Cartesian coordinate. In order to take into account the general setting (differential calculus on a manifold) the answer would be more complex.

Apparently you have deleted the comment down from my answer.

Comment: nice..........+1